# RavenDB spatial search - session.Query returning different results from session.Advanced.LuceneQuery

Tags: c#, ravendb

I'm a bit confused about the following two queries. With my limited understanding I think they're supposed to be identical, but while the session.Advanced.LuceneQuery version returns the results I'm expecting, the session.Query version returns fairly random-looking results, certainly more than 50 miles from the given location.

I'd prefer to use session.Query as I'm chaining multiple where clauses to it, which I can't do with the IDocumentQuery returned by the LuceneQuery.

Am I misunderstanding the purpose between the two types of query?

```
var query1 = session.Query<AccItem, AccItems_Spatial>()
    .Customize(x => x.WithinRadiusOf(radius: 50, latitude: (double)search.Lat, longitude: (double)search.Lon));

var query2 = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<AccItem, AccItems_Spatial>()
    .WithinRadiusOf(radius: 50, latitude: (double)search.Lat, longitude: (double)search.Lon);
```

Comment: Please can you include the code for your 'AccItems_Spatial' index?

Answer (score 0):

Both Query and LuceneQuery actually boil down to the exact same thing happening, so I am surprised to hear that there are differences between them.
Can you create a failing test and send it to the mailing list?

Note also that you *can* chain multiple where clauses in LuceneQuery

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can come up with a test. Regarding chaining, I'm trying to chain conditionally (ie adding a "where" clause only if a search parameter has been specified) and the compiler is complaining about casting an IEnumerable<AccItem> to IDocumentQuery<AccItem>.